# Number of planar graphs, given an embedding

Tags: graphs, lower-bounds, upper-bound

I want to find an upper bound on the number of planar graphs with $n$ vertices, assuming that we are given some embedding for those vertices beforehand. In particular, Im interested in either showing for every embedding there is $2^{o(n\log(n))}$ planar graphs, or showing that there exists an embedding with $2^{\Omega(n\log(n))}$ different planar graphs.

I know that without fixing embedding there is $2^{\Theta(n\log(n))}$, but my question differs from it since we fix an embedding beforehand.

I believe that still there is an embedding with $2^{\Omega(n\log(n))}$, but I couldn't prove or disprove it. [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136644/showing-asymptotic-lower-bound-on-log-of-recurrence) is an attempt I made to try and calculate the number of planar graphs for some embedding I believed would be "hard", but it didn't work out as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pach and Wenger proved in their paper [Embedding planar graphs at fixed vertex locations](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ewenger.4/papers/plembed.pdf) that if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are $n$ different points on the plane, then every planar graph on $n$ vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ has a planar embedding in which $v_i$ is found at position $p_i$.

Comment: This sounds too good to be true... I would expect that there would be *less* planar graphs if we fix the embedding beforehand. But what you are saying is that this number is exactly the same. Right?

Comment: That’s what Pach and Wenger are saying, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: Hmmm. If I understood correctly, they allow for edges to take any path. I didn't state it in the question, but im looking at graphs whose edges are linear segments (they connect with a direct line their two endpoints). Thanks! I will post another question with this added to it